# android studio project to javaFX?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, javafx

Is it possible to convert and android studio project to javaFX?

We already got the android project but we need it on javaFX, the thing is that we don't know very much about javaFX and I read that it's possible to convert javaFX to android but, is it possible to the opposite?

Comment: No, the life cycle is completely different. Android uses Activities, but there is no equivalent in JavaFX. You could perhaps make process a bit faster by writing a program that converts android layout xmls to fxml files+controller, but you have to fill in the controller logic on your own...

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Learn about FXML/JavaFX,determine suitable replacements for your Android views and write some code that reads the android layouts and writes the fxmls and controllers. Note that this is a complicated task and isn't worthwhile,unless you need to convert many layouts.If you've got few enough android layouts simply converting the layouts manually will probably be faster.Another option would be using SceneBuilder to design the scene.However I recommend learning the basics of JavaFX layouts before starting this. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am wrong but I don't think it is possible to convert android project to javaFX. You need to do your javaFX application from scratch.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm
- https://medium.com/the-java-report/javafx-step-by-step-part-1-getting-started-with-javafx-180d0517a8cf